# Operator overloading confustion C++

Tags: c++

```
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, date &d)
{
    return o << d.year << d.month << d.day;
}


std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, date &d)
{
    o << d.year << d.month << d.day;
    return o;
}
```

Which of these is correct syntax or are they both correct and interchangable?
Also,in which all cases we need curly braces,any rule for that,its too confusing.

Comment: Neither. The return type of an ostream overload must be the stream after you are done with it.  `Return o;` is always the last line of an ostream overload.

Comment: Beside the typos you have the two versions are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

**Some comments.**

First of all, I encourage you to keep `std::` before the objects of the standart library. This avoids a lot of name conflicts problems.

For me, the second version is better, due to the fact that `operator <<` can be overloaded by other users, and sometimes, it's not well written, and the return is missing. Then, the first syntax will fail.

Moreover, in general, dump an object in a stream doesn't modify it. Then, pass the object const.

Then, in my opinion, the best is the following :

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Date& date)
{
  out << date.year << "-" << date.month << "-" << date.day;
  return out;
}
```

Comment: And, in most cases, you need to declare this operator as friend for Date class to access private fields

Comment: @dFionov alternatively to the friend you can use public methods if available. You could even consider redirecting the oerator to a public `printToStream` method that does the actual work.

Comment: @dFionov : No ! `friend` is generaly the reflect of a design problem. The solution of Arne Mertz is the better in my opinion : create a method `Date::print(std::ostream& out) const` and call it from `operator <<`.